# Dropzone.js: how to cancel uploads when dropping new file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

Using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) I need to implement a way when a user drop a file into Dropzone all current uploads (if any) are canceled so only the current one gets uploaded.

I need a way to select and delete those.

I can do `MyDropzone.processQueue` to get the uploading queue files. I can also do `MyDropzone.removeAllFiles()` but this removes all items (uploading or uploaded).

I don't understand how can I apply the `removeAllFiles()` method only to the files that are in `MyDropzone.processQueue`.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Dropzone provides methods for this, as well as a `addRemoveLinks` option that inserts links to cancel/remove uploads.

Comment: I did this but when i click on cancel upload is is showing me that file is not uploaded, but it's actually uploaded in back side.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("#mydropzone").dropzone({
    init: function() {
        var $this = this;
        $("button#clear-dropzone").click(function() {
            $this.removeAllFiles(true);
        });
    }
});
```